# Drupal - Image in view followed by ,1

Tags: drupal

Drupal 7.34 here.
I have a content type that contains an image (multiple) field.
I created a view that shows only two fields: the title and the first image of the image field.
I have set the "Multiple field settings to "Display all values in the same row", set it to " Simple separator ", cleared the "Separator" field and set it to  Display 1 value(s)
The output is quite right, except that the image is always followed by 1 (the number 1)
Before I cleared the "," in the "Separator" field my images where followed by ,1 
So I managed to remove the comma but I don't have a clue where that 1 comes from and how to remove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
I use the Grid Field Formatter-module as a display for the image content type.
If I disable the Grid Formatter option for the image content type, the trailing 1 disappears...
So it must be an issue within the Grid Field Formatter-module